# failed enter ruby on rails console envirnment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i am new in ruby on rails. when i try this command " rails console " these errors displays :

```
/home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `block in require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `block in require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `block in require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:58:in `console'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `block in require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
    from /home/farnaz/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `load'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `block in load'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `load'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/farnaz/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

could you help me please ?

sure, this is my gem file : source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.0.beta4'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem  'rake'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'arel',                    '6.0.0.beta2'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'

## gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'

gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'unicorn',        '4.8.3'
end

Comment: try gem install rb-readline

Comment: tnx, i try it but error is same

Comment: can you show us whats in your Gemfile?

Comment: dear mr.Tom i added my gem file to post, could you check it please and help me.